# Is there any way to generate unique numbers in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to generate unique numbers in python? Sort of like a database primary key?

And the `random` module of python can sometimes generate the same number. I want it to be completely unique.

Comment: _how_ unique? Unique for only one run of your program, or on the other extreme, globally unique until eternity?

Comment: you can use random.sample to generate numbers without duplicates

Comment: `itertools.count`

Comment: @MSalters unique until eternity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4()
# UUID('e052c11d-e8ae-4a3d-a3e8-10d428a2e935')
```

UUID is a solution to generate generic random and unique values used as id. If you want in integer random and unique, you need a database or another data management system.

Comment: but can't there be just a _little_ chance that two UUIDs can be the same

Comment: @arnu515: There is a chance. `uuid.uuid1()` is not random and is guaranteed unique.

Answer (score 2):

You can use time and then hash the output

```
import time
now = time.time()
print(now)
print(hash(now))
```

the output is:

```
1586515688.2441766
563032968135724776
```

with this way you have unique number forever.

Comment: Is this in milliseconds or seconds, the time?

Comment: The integer part of time.now() function returns the seconds passed since epoch as an argument and returns a string representing local time. The "epoch" is defined as the start of January 1st, 1970 in UTC

Comment: that seems unique enough to me, currently using the first answer. IF that doesn't work, I'll use this one. Thanks OP

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# create a (5, 5) array containing unique integers drawn from [0, 100]
uarray = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 101), replace=False, size=(5, 5))

# check that each item occurs only once
print((np.bincount(uarray.ravel()) == 1).all())
# True
```